# React Js binding array object to mui-datatables

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to bind the data return from the grpc server to react js client. I am using  `react mui-data-tables` to display the data. In the browser of my console, I am getting the response object. But when I pass the response object to function  `DatatablePage(value)` data-table does not display the data. Below is the value which I am getting from grpc and passing to DatatablePage(value). Please do suggest to me, How I can solve this issue.

```
let value = {"validatorsList":[{"publicKey":"wtmQ/lZiD+D2i3LyloItrGgRyjSpAsRE9kc0vl6qZgljp2GpXTAWvBDTiegmIPUJIEUZyqZy9xGDm46QK5M9ounarW0gGJ/ZZ/fMQqxfiq9AFvYlAPlDuN4FRdEwq8UX","number":0,"sequence":0,"stake":0,"bondingHeight":0,"lastJoinedHeight":0}]}
```

```
function DatatablePage(value) {
  let jsonData = JSON.stringify(value);
  const columns = ["publicKey", "Number", "Sequence", "Stake", "Height"];
  const data = [jsonData[0].publicKey, jsonData[0].number];
  const options = {
    filterType: "checkbox",
  };

  return (
    <MUIDataTable
      title={"Validator List"}
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      options={options}
    />
  );
}
```